# Folded comments can't be retrieved when not logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments

When comments get folded in popular questions, the "show x more comments" link will not (or according to @Gabe's finding, sometimes not)  work if you are not logged in. Cursory debugging shows that the comments HTML does get loaded properly, but somehow isn't inserted into the DOM.

Repro:

- Log out of programmers.SE
- Go to [If you could pose a question to a Turing test candidate, what would it be?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64248/if-you-could-pose-a-question-to-a-turing-test-candidate-what-would-it-be)
- Scroll to the "Tortoise" answer
- Click the "show x more comments" link
- The link disappears, but no comments come up.

I think I have noticed this on other sites as well.

Tested in Chrome 10 and FF 4 on Windows 7.

Comment: Of all the ones I tried in IE8, the Tortoise one is the only one that didn't work.

Comment: Pekka, are you trolling? I didn't try to verify your post, just an odd feeling based on ... I don't know.

Comment: It's inserted into the DOM, it's just that loader isn't removing `.dno` from `#comments-64365`. The link should work fine for posts that already have at least one comment visible, since they don't have the `.dno` on their `.comments` element to begin with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice catch, considering you're presumably logged in most of the time.

We recently separated out the active (i.e. posting, editing, voting, etc.) and passive (i.e. reading) comment functionality in the JavaScript, as part of our quest to factor out parts that anonymous users don't actually need (so as to improve page load time for people arriving with an empty cache).

The code that removed the `display: none` from comment divs that initially were fully hidden  somehow got lost on that journey.

Fixed now.